# Can't ping or ssh but I can access websites through the browser

Tags: networking, ssh, ping

When I am connected to my work Wifi I can't ping or ssh from Ubuntu console.

```
>> ping google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.212.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
104 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 103039ms

>> ssh -i secret_key.pem ubuntu@secrethostaddress
ssh: connect to host secrethostaddress port 22: Connection refused
```

I can access all the websites via my browser. And when I am in my home's wifi I can ping and ssh. What could be going wrong with this wifi?

Comment: Your workplace has most likely a `Firewall` in place that blocks all traffic that is not for HTTP or HTTPS. So nothing is wrong. If you need access to SSH you may want to contact your local network admin.